# Replace %(text)s with __text__

Tags: bash, replace, sed

Some questions about sed/awk:

```
1. How to replace %(text)s with __text__

Example:

    %(vehicle)s -> __vehicle__
```

And second question:

```
2. How to make reverse operation: replace __text__ with %(text)s ?

Example:  

    __vehicle__ -> %(vehicle)s
```

Comment: Hint: use capture group and backreference.  You might want to refer to the manual too: http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/  Come back after attempting if you run into problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat test.txt
How to replace %(text)s with __text__
How to make backward operation: replace __text__ with %(text)s

$ sed 's#%(\([^)]*\))s#__\1__#g' test.txt
How to replace __text__ with __text__
How to make backward operation: replace __text__ with __text__

$ sed 's#__\([^_]*\)__#%(\1)s#g' test.txt
How to replace %(text)s with %(text)s
How to make backward operation: replace %(text)s with %(text)s
```

Note that capture group parantheses need escaping in `sed`.